# Entity Framework Core ignore null update

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

My EF models are like so:

```
public class Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    ...
}
```

My intention was to build the API in such a way that if you specify null on an update it would discard that value however it does not appear to work that way. In my repository update code I do the following:

```
public override IEnumerable<Base> Update(IEnumerable<Base> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items.OfType<Foo>())
    {
        var existingItem = _context.Foos.Find(item.Id);
        if (existingItem == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Can't update item of type `{typeof(Foo)}` as it doesn't exist. ");
        }

        var entry = _context.Entry(existingItem);
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(item);

        foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
        {
            var original = property.OriginalValue;
            var current = property.CurrentValue;
            property.IsModified = original != null && !original.Equals(current);
        }

        var collection = entry.Collection(nameof(Foo.Bars));
        if (collection.CurrentValue == null)
            collection.IsModified = false;
    }

    var rows = _context.SaveChanges();
    return Read(items.Select(e => e.Id));
}
```

Since the `Foo.Bars` property is actually a Collection/Navigation property there's no `OriginalValue` property to it, only a `CurrentValue` and this means I can't discard the value if it is null. Also it seems that setting the `collection.IsModified` to false has no effect and the `Foo.Bars` property is set to null regardless of the `IsModified` state.

Looking for advice on perhaps a better way to handle this or something I'm missing. Thanks.